# If null is a data type, why can't I assign a variable with type of null?

Tags: java, types

If I can do `int n = 0`, why can't I `null n = null`?
Isn't `null` a data type just like `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `null` is not a data type. `null` is a **value** (specifically to represent no valid value). Also, you can't assign `null` to a primitive.

Comment: theoretically speaking, `null` is a type which has no name. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1

Comment: @JerryChin Also from your link, *In practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference type.*

Comment: I can' agree with you more, let linguists sort it out.

Comment: @JerryChin Small distinction: `null` **has** a type (the "null type") which has no name.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt [Semantics](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9a/fd/6a/9afd6a24081ca81cbdbdcf676e4bd75c.jpg).

Comment: "Semantics" means "meaning", and meaning matters, @ElliottFrisch. The distinction between "value" and "type" in Java is pretty important. And the JLS makes it quite clear that the `null` literal is a value, not a type. "There is also a special _null type_, the type of the expression `null`". The typographical distinction is in the original. Don't treat semantics like it's trivial.

Comment: @LewBloch "The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null type." but more directly to OP's question "Because the null type has no name, it is impossible to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type." - if OP was implementing a JDK or compiler, then I wouldn't have posted a link to a punny cartoon ("No man" kills the witch-king)